# python-dependency-injector circularly interrelated packages

Tags: python, dependency-injection

When using subcontainers to organize layers in an application, there likely won't be circular dependencies between them. However, with domains this is not the case.

```
@dataclass
class UserService:
    payments: "PaymentsService"

    def user_action(self):
        print("user action")
        self.payments.payment_action


@dataclass
class PaymentsService:
    users: UserService

    def payment_action(self):
        print("payment action")


class UserContainer(containers.DeclarativeContainer):
    payments = providers.DependenciesContainer()

    service = providers.Factory(UserService, payments=payments.service)


class PaymentContainer(containers.DeclarativeContainer):
    users = providers.DependenciesContainer()

    service = providers.Factory(PaymentsService, users=users.service)



class ApplicationContainer(containers.DeclarativeContainer):
    users = providers.Container(UserContainer, payments=???)
    payments = providers.Container(PaymentContainer, users=users)
```

What's there to do if in the outermost container I want to link packages with circular dependencies between them?